# Starred chat message with a comment is not parsed well

Tags: bug, comments, chat, hyperlinks, chat-stars

[This chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41020094#41020094) contains a link to the comment of the post. Chat message is starred, and in the starboard link not correctly parsed:

> [image: star link]

In particular clickable part of the link refers to the question instead of comment.